# Refactor class method to property using Pycharm

Tags: python, properties, refactoring, pycharm, automated-refactoring

I have the following class:

```
class Dogs(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.names = []
        self.breeds = set()

    def number(self):
        return len(self.names)
```

I want to change `number` to being a property. This means I also want to change all of it usages. Does PyCharm have this built into it's refactoring tools? It seems to be according to [this issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-17341).

At this point, I'm doing "find all usages" and then manually fixing each instance. If there isn't a specific refactoring tool for changing a method to a property, is there some way to use "find all usages" more effectively?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, you can refactor a method to a property in PyCharm. Strangely, this does not correspond to any entry in the "Refactor" menu.

Just place the editor cursor on the name of the method and press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>⏎</kbd> shortcut to show the available [Intentions](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/intention-actions.html).

Then, select "Convert method to property".

[image: "Convert method to property" intention]

You can also trigger the global action search with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> and select the intention from there.

[image: Alternative]

Comment: Strangely, the inverse operation isn't available :)